# Session user images load but not images from everyother user? Grails

Tags: image, grails

Images by session or logged in user load and displayed fine but images from users other than session users won't get displayed. note: url for every images load just fine its just images aren't displayed.

Image controller:

```
def thumbphoto = {
    response.setContentType('image/jpeg')
    response.setHeader('Cache-control', 'no-cache')

    if(params?.id != null && !(params?.id.empty)){
      params.maxWidth?: 50.00
      params.maxHeight?: 50.00
      response.outputStream << imageProxyService.loadThumbnailImage(params.id, securityService.passwordEncoder(userId.toString()))
    }
}
```

query for outputting image and slogan

```
def statusQuery = """SELECT c.user_account_id as userId, c.status_message as message, c.status_type as profile, se.id, se.photo FROM user_account se, status c
                    WHERE
                    c.user_account_id = se.id
                    GROUP BY se.id, c.user_account_id, c.status_message, c.status_type, se.photo"""
```

displaying images in gsp:

```
<g:each in="${statusList}" status="i" var="status" status="i">
            <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">
            <tr>
              <td>

                  <img id="profile_photo" src="${createLink(controller:'image', action:'thumbphoto', id:status.photo, params:[maxWidth:50.0,maxHeight:50.0])}" alt="" title="" />
            </td>
            <td>${status.id}: ${status.message}</td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting id 
`id:status.photo` and `params:[id:status.id]`

edit:
and not passing `userId`

try to create link and add userId in it:
`<img id="profile_photo" src="${createLink(controller:'image', action:'thumbphoto', id:status.photo, params:[userId:status.userAccount.id, maxWidth:50.0,maxHeight:50.0])}" alt="" title="" />`

Comment: thanks even if i remove the id from params it loads image url all right but doesn't display the image... @ivarPrudnikov

Comment: even if i try to remove session user from thumbphoto method in image controller it still does the same thing...

Comment: You are not passing `userId` so no user if nobody in session.

Comment: okay but how would i accomplish if i want to list all status with user info and image along with it.?

Comment: That depends on your model, from your query I see `c.user_account_id` this is why I did add example in my main answer containing `userId:status.userAccount.id` I am just not sure if you can access user Id in this way and if it is what you want

Comment: My image controller operates on photo variable so i need to pass photo var instead of userid(photo filename is stored in user table)
all this is done right and i can see the url loaded all right, its just images are displayed only for session user even when i remove session user in image controller.

Comment: From controller: `def userId = session.selectedUser.id if(params.userId){ userId = params.userId }` How can you expect non session userId if you do not pass userId to controller?

Comment: Yes, If i remove user session syntex I could get the Image url loaded all right but images wont display in the browser. I have updated the main question with my current code.. @ivarPrudnikov

Comment: Are you able to get bytes from: `imageProxyService.loadThumbnailImage(params.id, securityService.passwordEncoder(userId.toString()))`, passing only `status.id` without `userId`?

Comment: @ivarPrudinkov - I removed user session user line of code and its starting to show photo id and url right but image still won't display.